# How to Add Members into Dictionary during Class declaration

Tags: c#

How can I add other member (during declaration of class) into dictionary? Are there any workarounds?  (this is just an example, that doesnt work, but shows what i want to achieve.

```
public class X{

      private Dictionary<string, string() texts = new Dictionary<string, string(){}; 
      .....
      .....
      .....
      .....
      ..... //hundreds of lines here
      .....
      .....
      .....
      .....
      texts["xyz"] = "hello";     // <---  I want to add it here, not in top. but now it fires error, as this should have happened in method as I see

      // constructor
      public X(){

      }
}
```

P.S. I DONT NEED ONE-LINE DECLARATION, LIKE `...  = new Dictionary<string, string(){  {"xyz", "hello"} };`

Comment: What is the error you get? What have you tried? And it is very different if it is an array or a dictionary. Which do you have?

Comment: We need a proper [mcve] - right now it seems like you are trying to set an array element outside any method

Comment: cannot be done in declaration, make a constructor for the class

Comment: Are you asking how to initialize: `private string[] texts = new[]{"hello", "world"};  `

Comment: You can either set the values dynamically in the constructor or declare a static array to begin with.

Comment: you can not access to `[1]` of empty array, you did not specify size of it.

Comment: @GiladGreen lets say, dictionary (i've updated question)

Comment: @T.Todua The line `texts["xyz"] = "hello";` is still outside any method, which is simply not allowed in C#

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in c#, you should do it in the constructor

```
public X()
{
    texts["xyz"] = "hello"; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand your problem, you need to use dynamic features of the C# language. Your question is not clear though. Anyway, you can do something like this:

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();

x.texts = new string[] { "zero", "one" };
x.//hundreds of lines here
x.texts[1] = "sdfgsdfg";
x.someMoreTexts = new string[] { "0", "1" };
```

Comment: I know that is possible inside method, but I say that I want to do that where `private int .....` declarations occur, not in method or constructor.